# Converting 78.3 F (nvarchar) to 78.3 (numeric)

Tags: sql-server, casting

Good afternoon, all!

Trying to get temperature off a database on my SQL server stored as "78.3 F" and make it only the number "78.3".  The database has this field as nvarchar.  I tried:

```
select
Cast(Left(Paint_Environ.Booth1_Temp, Len(Paint_Environ.Booth1_Temp) - 2) As NUMERIC(4,1)) As Temp
from Paint_Environ
```

but get an errors saying "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"  Is there a better way to convert nvarchar to something numeric???

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: Your code should work on the sample date "78.3 F" , do you have any other format in the data?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, your code should work with data `'78.3 F'`

You may try this

```
SELECT
   CAST(REPLACE(Booth1_Temp,'F','') AS NUMERIC(4,1)) As Temp
FROM Paint_Environ
```

**UPDATE**:
You may start debug with this to see which data format give you error

```
SELECT   Booth1_Temp 
FROM Paint_Environ
WHERE  ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(Booth1_Temp,'F','')) <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, EricZ!  I still get that error though.  I'll try the replace and maybe trim that...will advise.

Comment: Works great if I use RTrim(Replace(Paint_Environ.Booth1_Temp, 'F', '')) As Temp,